# can we convert a string (that is generated from a class object using toString Methode ) to json object in java.. how?

Tags: java, json

I have a string variable containing a string that is generated by toString method from an object of a class,

```
**String s= "LeadEnquiry [id=6,
 leadId=Lead [id=2, name=RICHARDO STALMANN, location=LA, gender=male, createdBy=admin123], createdBy=admin1234]"**
```

Is it possible to convert this type of string into a JSON object in Java, so then I could get any field by name.

Comment: This is one example, but the `toString` method can be overridden to return something completely different.

Comment: Why not access the fields directly or at least do a direct object to json conversion? This feels like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) so what are you trying to achieve in the end?

Comment: @MauricePerry In fact, the output as shown is already an overridden, custom format.